# How to Set Path Variable in pom.xml - Maven

Tags: angular, maven, gruntjs, pom.xml

I am trying to build a angular project through maven.  here are my steps

```
npm install
bower install
grunt build
```

first two are successful, during the third step, i am getting compass not found error.

i am able to run successfully in my local as Ruby is added in PATH but in Jenkin server it is failing as no PATH set up.

I am looking for a option to pass the environmental variable -PATH through pom.xml.  can some one advice me how i can do that?

```
<execution>                     
    <id>exec-grunt-build</id>
    <phase>generate-sources</phase>
    <configuration>
        <workingDirectory>${project.resourcesfolder}</workingDirectory>
        <executable>${grunt_cmd}</executable>
        <arguments>
            <argument>build</argument>
        </arguments>
        <environmentVariables>
            <path>${ruby_home}/bin</path>
        </environmentVariables>
    </configuration>
    <goals>
        <goal>exec</goal>
    </goals>
</execution>
```

`Warning: not found: compass`

Ant Equavelent  [ just looking maven version of the below code ]

```
<env key="PATH" path="${ruby_home}/bin"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

this helped to solve the issue.

```
<execution>
    <id>exec-grunt-build</id>
    <phase>generate-sources</phase>
    <configuration>
        <workingDirectory>${project.resourcesfolder}</workingDirectory>
        <executable>${grunt_command}</executable>
        <arguments>
            <argument>build</argument>
        </arguments>
        **<environmentVariables>
            <PATH>${ruby_home}\bin</PATH>
        </environmentVariables>**
    </configuration>

    <goals>
        <goal>exec</goal>
    </goals>
</execution>
```